# mercure docker cannot configure properly problem with CORS

Tags: reactjs, docker, mercure

I try for a bunch of hours to configure my mercure with docker
I didn't manage to solve the corss issue :

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header is present on the requested resource

I have this docker-compose file

extract

```
  mercure:
    image : dunglas/mercure
    volumes:
      - ./mercure/caddy:/etc/caddy
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=localhost
      - MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=changeIt
      - MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=changeIt
      - MERCURE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1
```

And this Caddyfile :

```
# The address of your server
localhost

:80
route {
    mercure {
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt changeIt
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt changeIt
        cors_origins http://localhost:3000
    }

    respond "Not Found" 404
}
```

my request on client side is in React

```
http.get('/api/mercure').then( response => {
            this.setCookie( response.data.token);
            const url = new URL('http://localhost:8081/.well-known/mercure');
            url.searchParams.append('topic', 'http://agora.org/votes/{id}');
            const eventSource = new EventSource(url, {withCredentials: true});
            eventSource.onmessage = (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            }
        },error => {
            console.log( error);
        })
```

Can someone help me out of this ?
Thx in advance

Comment: this is linked to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65124697/can-not-configure-the-new-dunglas-mercure-image

Comment: Have you tried removing the `MERCURE_` prefix from your environment variables in your docker compose file?  I'm not seeing anything at https://mercure.rocks/docs/hub/config indicating that's necessary

Comment: Yes I tried, with no effects. I think the problem is elsewhere. Maybe the server crash before sending the header. There is an issue with https. Because its redirecting to 443

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used the Mercure with `docker-compose` without the CORS issue. You can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/ssi-anik/sse-with-mercure/blob/master/docker-compose.yml.example#L63-L77).

As I have reached here, someone else may also reach here as well and may help that person too.